# How to sign-in to bitbucket?

Tags: session, cookies, authentication, bitbucket

I would like to sign-in with my Google credentials on BitBucket, but each time I go to

https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/

I am redirected to

https://bitbucket.org/socialauth/signup/?next=/

Which is not what I want.

I also removed all the cookies related to Atlassian and Bitbucket, but I don't know to to wipe all the used internal storage for this particular website.

Any idea?

It seems I am not the only one with this [issue](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Why-suddenly-cannot-login-Redirects-to-choose-user-name/qaq-p/324585)

It works from the incognito page, so it is somehow cookie related,but I don't want to remove all my cookies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to login from another browser? 
Or try to login with your `github` account if it work.

If is your fist time with that gmail account note that you need to create it

You can make a "force refresh" with `SHIFT+F5` in the page, or if you are using google chrome you can wipe all cookies & data with [this guide](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-clear-cache)

*Sorry for my bad english.*

Comment: It works from the incognito mode, so it is related to the cookies. I wiped the bitbucket cookies but it seems not enough and I don't want to remove ALL my cookies

Comment: have you tried this? [link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Can-t-login-to-bitbucket/qaq-p/508610)